# Black pixels on my Android Emulator upon boot up

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

so I have a problem with my Android Emulator. It shows black pixels on the screen upon boot up. I'm just learning Flutter but it's so irritating to see this:

[image]

Is there something I must do to fix this? Been googling  this for 2 days and no answers can be found..am I the only one encountering this? Hoping for your guys help..btw.. I've also turned the boot option to "Cold  Boot" since it's much more  better they say than a quick boot. Then I've adjusted the Internal Storage to 4096mbb but keeping the RAM at 1536mb and VM Heap to 256mb. I've also wiped the user data clean but the black pixels still show.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the "Emulated Performance" - "Graphics" to "Software - GLES 2.0" fixed it for me